# How to move the WordPress site Layout from test site to Production site?

Tags: database, migration, server

I make the changes in the Layout of the test site, and on the other hand my production (live) site was running and people make account on that and make purchases.

**Now I want to transfer the test site to the production site but I did not want to change the database**,
mean I want to use the layout of the test site and database of the production site.

Can any one guide me that How can I do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean “changes in the layout”? Have you been editing theme files? Or editing the site with your themes customisation options? Or using a page builder?

Comment: I customize the some pages on the front end with the wp custom builder. and now I want that changes on my production site but I dont want any change in the production database @JacobPeattie

Comment: What is "the wp custom builder"? Do you mean the Customizer (_Appearance > Customize_)?

Comment: @JacobPeattie 'wp custom builder' meani gutenberg, Elementor etc